# Как изменить ссылку на другую таблицу в PostgresSql?

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет!
У меня есть таблица с столбцами:

```
create table  app_public.category (
    id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid(),
    parent_id uuid default null
);
```

как мне изменить столбец parent_id на следующее значение:

```
parent_id uuid references app_public.category on delete cascade
```

?
Сейчас этот столбец пустой, поэтому сохранять старые значения не требуется..

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE app_public.category
    ADD CONSTRAINT category__parent_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES app_public.category (id);
```